# Accessing property on object in an array in a ternary

Tags: javascript, arrays, ternary-operator

I had an interesting situation and was wondering if anyone knew why. 
I had this statement in my code

```
var score = (typeof k.rewards !== 'undefined') ? k.rewards[0].value : k.value;
```

This would throw an error of value being undefined within the array (on the truthy side of the ternary). However, I know the value is there and this will print it just fine.

```
var score = (typeof k.rewards !== 'undefined') ? k.rewards : k.value;
Console.log(score[0].value);
```

does anyone know why it would be undefined when I try to access it directly in the ternary?

Comment: could you add the code for generating the array?

Comment: Could you please show the rewards type and structure?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case, https://jsfiddle.net/1wmefa6p/

Comment: Use this expression instead: `var score = k.rewards && k.rewards.length? k.rewards[0].value : k.value;`

Answer (score 2):

Well, your first expression is equivalent to

```
(typeof k.rewards !== 'undefined' ? k.rewards[0] : k).value
```

while your second one is equivalent to

```
(typeof k.rewards !== 'undefined' ? k.rewards : k.value)[0].value
```

I hope you can see the difference now…

> This would throw an error of value being undefined within the array (on the truthy side of the ternary).

Not exactly. Your first one does throw when `k.rewards[0]` is `undefined`, and you nonetheless try to access its `.value` property. If `k.rewards[0]` existed, but had no `.value` property, it wouldn't throw but just yield `undefined`. You might want to test for `k.rewards.length > 0` as well in your condition:

```
(k.rewards && k.rewards.length ? k.rewards[0] : k).value
```

Comment: ok but they both have value. the above statement should work. I am getting remote data and the structure could either be k.rewards[0].value or k.value. The rewards.length thing could be the problem tho